# WHAT IS WRONG WITH THIS CODE [windos phone 8.1 development] C# and Xaml

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

im new to windows dev with c# and xaml. learning with rob miles "blue book" for win8 dev.

I keep getting this error message and im stuck. could someone please help me out or give me some pointers. I have added a comment at the block that is giving me trouble.
thanks

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation;
using AddingMachine;

namespace AddingMachine
{
    public class Customer
    {
        public string Name { get; set;}

        public string Address{ get; set;}

        public int ID { get; set;}

        public Customer(string inName, string InAddress, int inID)
        {
            Name = inName;
            Address = InAddress;
            ID = inID;
        }
    }

    public class Customers
    {
        public string Name { get; set;}

        public List<Customer> CustomerList;
        public Customers(string inName)
        {
            Name = inName;
            CustomerList = new List<Customer>();
        }
        Customers mailCustomers = new Customers("Mail Order Customers");
        private Customers customerList;

        public static Customers MakeTestCustomers()
        {
            string[] firstNames = new string[] { "Rob", "Jim", "Joe", "Nigel", "Sally", "Tim" };
            string[] lastsNames = new string[] { "Smith", "Jones", "Bloggs", "Miles", "Wilkinson", "Brown"};

            Customers result = new Customers("Test Customers");
            int id = 0; foreach (string lastName in lastsNames)
            {
                foreach (string firstname in firstNames)
                {
                    //Construct a customer name 
                    string name = firstname + " " + lastName;
                    //Add the new customer to the list 
                    result.CustomerList.Add(new Customer(name, name + "'s House", id));
                    // Increase the ID for the next customer 
                    id++;
                }
            }
            return result;

            // THIS IS WHERE I AM HAVING PROBLEM. "customers" object keep showing error msg that it does not exit in the current context.
            customers = Customers.MakeTestCustomers();
            foreach (Customer c in customers.CustomerList)
            {
                TextBlock customerBlock = new TextBlock();
                customerBlock.Text = c.Name;
                customersStackPanel.Children.Add(customerBlock);
                //customers = Customers.MakeTestCustomers(); customerList.ItemsSource = customers.CustomerList;
                //customerList = Customers.MakeTestCustomers();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

XAML

```
<Page
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:AddingMachine"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:App1="using:AddingMachine"
    xmlns:App11="using:App1"
    x:Class="AddingMachine.MainPage"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

   <!--<StackPanel x:Name="customersStackPanel" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="9,6,0,0"  VerticalAlignment="Top" ScrollViewer.BringIntoViewOnFocusChange="True"/>-->
    <ListBox Name="customerList"  SelectionChanged="customerList_SelectionChanged">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel x:Name="customersStackPanel" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="9,6,0,0"  VerticalAlignment="Top" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode="Auto">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" 
                               Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextExtraLargeStyle}"/>

                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Address}" 
                               Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextExtraLargeStyle}"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>


</Page>
```

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: The message is pretty clear. You never defined a variable called `customers`.

Comment: Also, "WHAT IS WRONG WITH THIS CODE [windos phone 8.1 development] C# and Xaml" is a *reaaally* bad title for a question.

Comment: Hi isreal, @dcastro thats the way it was in the book. I have tried creating a customer variable but then the "customerStackPanel.Children..." would also start showing error message " customerStackPanel" does not exits in the context even though its being refrenced from xaml.

Comment: @codecraft please show the xaml and lets try to figure it out

Comment: @israelalter Ive added the xaml code

Comment: There is no stack panel with that name, there is one with "customersStackPanel", note the "s" after "customer". Though the code in the question refers to the correct one, did that other error pop up somewhere else, in code you've not posted?

Comment: Wouldn't the call to `customers = Customers.MakeTestCustomers();` end causing a `StackOverFlowException` due to the recursive call?

Comment: That line of code will never execute anyway and is redundant, its going to return from the method before it gets there....your error is simply a compile error.

Comment: @MattC Yes, it will. I'm assuming that OP has changed the code slightly from the book he has been reading. If not, well... He should get a refund.

Comment: @BenjaminPaul aha yes, missed that!

Comment: Thanks guys, I know books are prone to errors but first I'd have to use it to get a hang of it before trying out my understanding. for someone that is learning I'd never know when a code is logically wrong or redundant.

Answer (score 2):

**Books can be prone to mistakes**, copying something directly out of a book probably won't help you to learn much as opposed to trying things out on your own. If there is an error in the book, then the book is wrong, not the compiler. The book isn't the law, the compiler is.

As to your actual problem, as **dcastro** pointed out, you have not declared a variable called `customers`. Perhaps you meant to use `customerList` instead.

When you find an error, take a few moments to read through your code and understand exactly what's going on. Error messages are usually pretty clear on the problem.

Comment: I have tried that on my own, I know I'm supposed to create the cusomers varialbe, but when i did create the customers variable the "customersStackPanel.Children..."object would also put up "customersStackPanel" does not exist in this context even though its clear its being refrenced from xaml. I'm just lost

Comment: **customersStackPanel** is an element of your `View`. You cannot reference this in your class, you can only reference it in the View's code-behind.